# How to make a correlation matrix with p-values shown and axes partly italic

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, correlation

I have a dataset consisting of 26 different species of birds which I have made Spearman correlation on in cran R. I want to show my result as a correlation matrix with colors. My problem is that the axes need to have the birds Danish names in normal text followed by their latin name in italics. Furthermore I need the matrix to show which correlations are significant.

I have tried to use ggcorrplot, where I can make the non-significant correlations blank, but I can't figure out how to change the names on the axes.

I have also tried to use cor and ggplot where I can change the name on the axes (I have just shown the code for one of the axes in the script because it takes up a lot of space), but I can't figure out how I could show which correlations are non-significant or significant.

In the script below I have made the code fit the dataset mtcars that is available in R.

## correlation ggcorrplot

```
library(ggcorrplot)
data("mtcars")

correlation <- cor(mtcars, method = "spearman")
p.mat <- cor_pmat(mtcars)
ggcorrplot(corr = correlation, type = "lower", insig = "blank", p.mat = p.mat)
```

[image]

## correlation cormat and ggplot

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)

cormat <- cor(mtcars, method = "spearman")
get_lower_tri <- function(cormat) {
  cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- NA 
  return(cormat)
} 

low_tri <- get_lower_tri(cormat) 
melted_cormat <- melt(low_tri, na.rm = TRUE)

ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white", midpoint = 0, limit = c(-1,1), space = "Lab") + scale_y_discrete(labels = c(expression('mpg'~italic("mpg")), expression('cyl'~italic("cyl")), expression('disp'~italic("disp")), expression('hp'~italic("hp")), expression('drat'~italic("drat")), expression('wt'~italic("wt")), expression('qsec'~italic("qsec")), expression('vs'~italic("vs")), expression('am'~italic("am")), expression('gear'~italic("gear")), expression('carb'~italic("carb"))))
```

[image]

The result I'm looking for should have the axes from the ggplot, but show the significant correlation as the ggcorrplot. The significant correlation can also be shown with X over insignificant or stars for p-value, I just need a kind of representation of the p-value on the plot.

Comment: If it's just changing names, maybe use `theme` to do that?

Comment: Or just add the +`scale_y_discrete` to the `ggcorrplot`?

Comment: @NelsonGon thank you very much, I didn't know I could just use +scale_y_discrete to the other plot. That solved the problem.

Comment: if you have a solution to your problem, you may (= are encouraged to) post it as an answer!